# How high light search text in RecyclerView adapter

Tags: android, highlight, android-recyclerview

I used `RecyclerView` and custom Adapter in my app ... adapter be implements Filterable for search. How to set high light search text ?

This my code for filterable in custom  adapter :

```
private Filter filterResult = new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
            ArrayList<Moment> tempList = new ArrayList<>();
            if (MOMENT_FILTER != null) {
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(constraint)) {
                    tempList = (ArrayList<Moment>) MOMENT_FILTER;
                } else {
                    int length = MOMENT_LIST.size();
                    int i = 0;
                    while (i < length) {
                        Moment item = MOMENT_FILTER.get(i);
                        if (item.getMoment().contains(constraint))
                            tempList.add(item);
                        i++;
                    }
                }
            }
            filterResults.values = tempList;
            filterResults.count = tempList.size();
            return filterResults;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            MOMENT_LIST = (ArrayList<Moment>) results.values;
            if (results.count > 0) {
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return filterResult;
    }
```

And this my code in activity for text change (EditText) :

```
EDT_SEARCH.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                adapter.getFilter().filter(s);
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }
});
```

result is OK with Sahil answer!

Comment: I am new to android and I have a similar question. Can you help me with it?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60930395/how-to-highlight-the-searched-letters-in-recycler-view

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a reference of the searchText in your adapter
then in your OnBindViewHolder you can do as

```
String text = list.get(position).getText(); // Your getter Method
String htmlText = text.replace(searchText,"<font color='#c5c5c5'>"+searchText+"</font>");
// Only searchText would be displayed in a different color.
holder.textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(htmlText );
```

Comment: thanks, but i don't change Moment (database model) because used in any method !

Comment: Adding another parameter shouldn't effect your other model. as its not necessary to alter your other method's code

Comment: @ghasemdeh I have updated my answer. its tailored according to your requirement. please check

Comment: thanks dear Sahil ... but i need high light search text no complete text

Comment: @ghasemdeh you are using textview for displaying text right?

Comment: yes ! if (isFilteredMode){
                holder.TXT_NOTE.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#F7941F"));

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153544/discussion-between-sahil-manchanda-and-ghasem-deh).